# Jquery get visibility last item from an id to execute hidden function

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a html markup like this to show a .block one at a time with a click:

```
<div id="chat-wrapper">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
</div>

<div class="add-button">
  add
</div>
```

with jquery script for the .add-button:

```
$('.add-button').click(function() {
   $('#chat-wrapper').find('.block:hidden').first().css({ display: 'block' });
});
```

and of course, I set up the css for the block to:

```
.block {
  display:none;
}
```

Everything works fine for the click function to show the .block one at a time on click, but, I want to make refinement if the last item of the #chat-wrapper is already visible, it will hide the .add-button

If anyone has an idea to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the hidden collection and hide button when it is the last one

```js
$('.add-button').click(function() {
  const $hidden = $('#chat-wrapper .block:hidden');
  $hidden.first().show()
  if ($hidden.length === 1) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add-button">
  add
</button>
<div id="chat-wrapper">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
</div>
```